# Easiest way to import data from My Sql to Sql Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, import

For a new project I have to import the pre-existing data from MySql.

In [this site](http://www.connectionstrings.com/?carrier=mysql) I have found many options, some including the installation of drivers. What is the fastest & easiest way to do it?

Update: this would be just a one time import

Answer (score 8):

```
-- Create Link Server

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver 
@server = N'MYSQL', 
@srvproduct=N'MySQL', 
@provider=N'MSDASQL', 
@provstr=N'DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver}; SERVER=localhost; _
     DATABASE=tigerdb; USER=root; PASSWORD=hejsan; OPTION=3'

-- Import Data

SELECT * INTO testMySQL.dbo.shoutbox
FROM openquery(MYSQL, 'SELECT * FROM tigerdb.shoutbox')
```

Comment: I've used this. It works well to create the basic table schema and copy the rows (which is really nice). I didn't see my indexes or keys come over, though. I'm guessing some data types might fail, but so far so good. Thanks!

Comment: I'm running into all kinds of errors with this approach.  For example, varchar columns with lengths greater than 4000 require me to use the ANSI driver, otherwise it tries to create a nvarchar column and fails, because its maximum specified length is 4000.  Also, without configuring very specific options such as "Return SQL NULL DATA for zero date" and "Enable SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL" and "Bind minimal date as zero date", there more errors.  With no relevant options left to configure, I'm now getting "Error converting data type DBTYPE_DBTIMESTAMP to datetime2", and expect to encounter even more.

Comment: I did run into the problem stated as " "Error converting data type DBTYPE_DBTIMESTAMP to datetime ".  I have had to export the data from MySql first to CSV and then onwards to MS-SQL Server, both steps using Data Transformation Services saved as VB module file and it was quite smooth. Needless to say, the fields will be exported as varchar(8000). But that was better for me rather than DBType_DBTIMESTAMP fields not getting exported at all and breaking in between.

Answer (score 1):

To convert `MySQL to MS SQL Server` database you can use [Microsoft SQL Server Database Migration Assistant](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/product-info/migration-tool.aspx#MySQL)

Comment: This the current link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssma/

In addition to MySQL it supports Oracle, Sybase and MS Access.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to phpMyAdmin you could run an export of the entire database. It will generate a long list of SQL commands to create all the schema and optionally insert all the data into their respective places.

It is also possible to perform all this from the command line.

If you have a lot of data you may want to do it all in pieces, single SQL scripts for each table and the inserts into each.

Then on the M$ SQL side just create the database, connect to it with SQL Query Analyzer or SQL Management Studio, copy-n-paste your SQL scripts into the window and execute.

Chances are a majority of your MySQL code will just work in M$SQL. If you run into issues, you can set a compatibility level on the MySQL export to fit your destination environment better.

If your just doing data, as long as the schema's match up, all you have to script is the data import/export, don't script the schema and CERTAINLY DON'T script drops!!!

EDIT: if you had to do any transformations, I believe you can export to M$ Excel, certainly to a CSV, then on the M$SQL import do your mappings and such.

Answer (score 0):

My team recently did the opposite, SqlServer to MySql, using the MySql Migration Toolkit (for moving a Fogbugz install from Windows to Linux) and it worked very well.  We had trouble with a tool called MSSQL2MySql, it didn't work so well.  I'm not sure if the migration toolkit handles the opposite direction, but it might be worth a look.